# How to use the properties of Chebyshev polynominals to find the minmax value of the polynomal $|1-\alpha t|$

Tags: polynomials

I found in one book which said that using properties of Chebyshev polynomials, one can get
\begin{align*}
\underset{\alpha}{\rm min} \underset{\lambda_1\leq t\leq \lambda_n}{\rm max}|1-\alpha t|=\frac{\lambda_n-\lambda_1}{\lambda_n+
\lambda_1},
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_n\geq \lambda_1>0$.\par

I wonder how to prove it.

Comment: What are the $\lambda$'s?

Comment: Here,$ \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_n$  can be regarded as two constants, where $\lambda_n\geq \lambda_1>0$ and $\lambda_1\leq t\leq \lambda_n$.